# Why does vue emit not allow me to update parent data?

Tags: vue.js

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my code. The emit works fine for both methods if I only output to the console but if I update data in the parent methods only waitOnSocial runs and the socialFailed method doesn't run (with no error)?

Here is the code stripped down to the needed parts.

Child Method

```js
export default {
    methods: {
        socialSignIn(provider) {
            let previousPath = this.$route.params.previousPath;
            let self = this;
            self.$emit("wait");
            this.$store
                .dispatch("auth/login", { providerName: provider })
                .then((success) => {
                    if (success === true) {
                        this.$router.push(previousPath);
                    } else {
                        self.$emit("failed");

                        console.log("Social Auth Failed");
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('ERROR', err);
                    self.$emit("failed");
                });
        },
    },
};
```

Parent

```js
<template>
    <div class="login-container">
        <div
            v-if="isAuthenticated === undefined || !showForm"
            class="authorise-inner"
        >
            <i class="fas fa-unlock-alt"></i>
            Authorising
        </div>
        <div v-else class="login-inner">
            <base-form class="form-container">
                <h2>Hey, Welcome Back!</h2>
                <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    id="email"
                    v-model="input.email"
                />
                <div v-if="error.email" class="error">{{ error.email }}</div>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    ref="password"
                    v-model="input.password"
                />
                <div
                    @click="togglePass"
                    ref="passwordToggle"
                    id="toggle-pass"
                    class="hidden"
                ></div>
                <div v-if="error.password" class="error">
                    {{ error.password }}
                </div>
                <div class="forgot">
                    <router-link to="/request-password">
                        Forgot Password?
                    </router-link>
                </div>
                <div v-if="error.login" class="error">
                    {{ error.login }}
                </div>
                <BaseButton
                    @click.native.prevent="validateInput()"
                    text="Sign In"
                    type="primary"
                    class="full-width"
                />
            </base-form>
            <SocialLogin
                @wait="waitOnSocial"
                @failed="socialFailed"
                @toggleAuth="socialLoginInProgress"
                style="width: 100%"
            />
            <div class="register">
                Don't have an account?
                <router-link to="/signup">SIGN UP</router-link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

...
export default {
 data(){
   return{
    showForm:true,
   }
 }
 methods: {
        waitOnSocial() {
            console.log('passed');
            this.showForm = false;
        },
        socialFailed() {
            console.log('failed');
            this.showForm = true;
        },
       socialLoginInProgress() {
            console.log("fired");
            this.showForm = !this.showForm;
        },
 }
}
```

**To summarise waitOnSocial() and socialFailed() run if i comment out the update to this.showForm. But if update this.showForm then only waitOnSocial() runs and no error is given.**

Comment: The code is a little messy because I have been trying several things to fix it. Like splitting the emit into two methods and creating a variable to assign this.

Comment: what do you expect in the second time?

Comment: showForm is attached to a v-if bock. When the social login failed it should be visible again. If I update this.showForm in the parent, then socialFailed never fires and has no error. But if I only output to the console then both methods run correctly.

Comment: I thin you need to do `this.showForm = !this.showForm;`

Comment: I just tried making your changes by combining the methods but I get the same issue. The method runs the first time only. The second time it doesn't run and has no error. If I remove this.showForm = !this.showForm; then the method runs both times correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
self.$emit('failed',false);
```

```html
<SocialLogin @wait="waitOnSocial" @failed="(v)=>{socialFailed = v}" @toggleAuth="socialLoginInProgress" style="width: 100%" />
```

Refactor to direct emit payload.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work. The problem is that in your example socialFailed never runs if it contains an update to the parent data (this.showForm = true) so this.$forceUpdate(); doesn't get run either. Very strange because if I remove the data update it runs fine.

Comment: console.log runs every time if I don't update the data. It only runs the first time if I update data.

Comment: The typo was just on stack overflow, not in my local code. If I attach the methods to a button then the form toggles visibility, somewhere the emit is breaking

Comment: can you provide more code? The template part where you use showForm? The common typo is when you assign the value in template insted of expression. (showForm = false) (showForm == false)

Comment: Sure I just added the whole template for the parent.

Comment: `<SocialLogin @toggleAuth="socialLoginInProgress" style="width: 100%"/>` 
missing the events or its different part?

Comment: Sorry I am debugging while waiting for responses. I added back in the others.

Comment: debug in which case the emits run. After each self.$emit place a distinctive console log to see what block evaluates. in the dispatch process. The button is forcing the event so it is correct. Your issue propably lies in dispatch blocks.

Comment: waitOnSocial() and socialFailed() run if i comment out the update to this.showForm. But if update this.showForm then only waitOnSocial() runs and no error is given.

Answer (score 0):

try this.$emit

Because the this keyword has a different value in the function that is invoked by setInterval.

You already know the solution with the self variable in a closure, a different (and shorter) solution would be binding the emit method:

Comment: Originally I had it set using this.$emit, the self variable was an attempted solution. Binding the $emit method gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could find was a little hacky and instead of emitting in the child component I access the parent variable directly:

```
this.$parent.showForm = true;
```